# JavaScript: Evaluating export code directly from string

Tags: javascript, webpack

How does one run and resolve a JavaScript export module directly from a string?

Here's a concrete example: The module `vue-route-generator` generates export code that returns a Vue Router configuration object. So when I issue this command:

```
const routes = require('vue-route-generator').generateRoutes(...);
```

`routes` is a string containing code, something like this:

```
function index() {
  return import('/home/jay/Documents/industrial/resources/js/sections/index.vue');
}
function people() {
  return import('/home/jay/Documents/industrial/resources/js/sections/people.vue');
}

export default [
  { name: 'index', path: '/', component: index },
  { name: 'people', path: '/people', component: people },
];
```

How do I run this code and get the object without saving this code to a separate file? I'm using Webpack as my builder but a solution that works for other builders would be appreciated.

Comment: `eval(routes)`?

Comment: `export`. This is a module. Also, aren't we supposed to avoid using `eval`?

Comment: yes we are. But if you want to follow that maxim, don't put your code in strings in the first place.

Comment: I'm not. I'm getting a result from a module that is a code string.